# How do I link to classes together on java

Tags: java, user-interface, encoding, jframe, jcreator

I have 2 classes running on one project. One class is an implement and the other is a GUI, now what I want is for the GUI to seek code from the implement class. My program is a module Calculator, a user enters their coursework and exam scores in order to get their result.

**GUI CLASS**

```
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 class GUI{


public static void main(String[] args) {


        String result1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Coursework Result:");
        String result2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Exam Result:");


        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(result1);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(result2);
        int avg =  (num1 + num2)/2;

        String message = "";

        if (avg<40)
        message = "Your Test Score:  "+avg+"% Sorry But You Failed!";

        else if(avg<=120)
        message = "Your Test Score:  "+avg+"% Well Done, You Passed!";

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
}
```

}

**IMPLEMENT CLASS**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

public static void main (String[] args) {   

Scanner boykie = new Scanner (System.in);
short result1;
short result2;
int avg = 0;

System.out.println("Enter Coursework Result:");
result1=boykie.nextShort();
System.out.println("Enter Exam Result:");
result2=boykie.nextShort();

avg = (result1+result2)/2;

if (avg<40)
    System.out.println("Your Test Score:  "+avg+"% Sorry But You Failed!");

else if(avg<=100)
    System.out.println("Your Test Score:  "+avg+"% Well Done, You Passed!");



}

}
```

Comment: Well, you turn back to the books or the internet (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html is a good starting point) and you learn about objects and classes in Java. The point is: normally, you don't put all your functionality into a main method. You create classes that have methods; and then you can instantiate objects of classes ... within other classes to "link" them together.

Comment: Also, a proper GUI typically does not consist of displaying dialog boxes one after the other. A good GUI displays a window with fields and buttons in it, and calls functionality when the user does something with those controls, keeping the window open and allowing the user to continue to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no class linking in Java. What you have to do is,

- Create seperate *.java files
- Compile them with  javac -classpath .;c:\path_to_your_classes xxx.java
- Run your program by running java -classpath c:\path_to_your_classes xxx

-If you want to get a service from another class, you have to write a method with a non-private visibility, and call that method.

That said, it is always easier to use an IDE(Ex:Eclipse,Net Beans, etc..) to compile and run a Java program.

Comment: 6 years later I spend hours looking for this.